# Unicode RXVT and Xresources Settings

Tags: fedora, rxvt, x-resources

In Fedora 24, the Xresources file was automatically loaded. However in Fedora 25 I have to manually execute `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`. Does anyone know how to have the system auto-load Xresources?

Comment: Not familiar with Fedora, but it's usually controlled by scripts associated with the display manager. I use `xdm`, and I had to add it add some stage (way in the past) to those scripts. Concrete steps depend on which display manager you use (`gdm` for Gnome, `kdm` for KDE, `lightdm`, ...)